# Values are not updating in my text label from api calling

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have one api calling, and I am passing one parameter value to that api. And I am doing append to one model data and from there I am trying to display in my label. But when I do api calling itself and try to print the label name , Its showing crash index out of range

```
   func showprofileapi () {

        let headers = [
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
        ]

        let jsonObj:Dictionary<String, Any> = [
            "customerID" : "5"
                    ]

        if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObj)) {
            print("is not a valid json object")
            return
        }

        if let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://MyProfile.php")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    ///print(error)
                } else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                        {
                            let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                            if(status == 1)
                            {
                                print("SUCCESS....")
                                if (json["myprofile"] as? NSDictionary) != nil
                                {

                                    print("SUCCESS  ......22....")
                                    print(json)

                                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                        print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")



                                        self.Profileddatas.append(MyProfiledData(json:json as NSDictionary))

                                      print("Product Name : ", self.Profileddatas[0].custName)    


                                    })


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()
        }
     }
```

My above code is my api calling, And when I try to print the value in my console its crashing :

```
//  print("Product Name : ", self.Profileddatas[0].custName)
```

My json output after api calling is :

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "My Profile Details are.",
  "myprofile": {
    "CustomerName": "ram",
    "CustomerEmail": "ram@gmail.com",
    "CustomerMobile": "",
    "CustomerAddress": "",
    "CustomerUsername": "",
    "CustomerPassword": " "
  }
}
```

My append data model class is :

```
class MyProfiledData
{
    var custName : String?
    var custEmail : String?
    var custMobile : String?
    var custAddress : String?
    var custUsername : String?
    var custPassword : String?

    init(json:NSDictionary)
    {
        self.custName = json["CustomerName"] as? String
        self.custEmail = json["CustomerEmail"] as? String
        self.custMobile = json["CustomerMobile"] as? String
        self.custAddress = json["CustomerAddress"] as? String
        self.custUsername = json["CustomerUsername"] as? String
        self.custPassword = json["CustomerPassword"] as? String


    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: i made one changes in your code check it

Comment: print("Product Name : ", self.Profileddatas[0].custName)  this line i made changes

Comment: Its showing nill value !!1

Comment: What i am doing wrong, If it append correctly  - then why its showing nill ??

Comment: Did i am doing wrong in making it as nsdict instead of nsarray or any other wrong thing i am doing

Comment: make break point in to your append value method in MyProfiledData class

Comment: its showing `(lldb) ` only for all the value append values in my my profileData class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126494/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-mack).

Comment: Please check my json output that i have posted, is nsdic or should i have to make it some other ?? for my both append value and for my data model class

Comment: The NSDictionary has no problem, it's just you're accessing its value by the wrong keys (checkout my Answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (json["myprofile"] as? NSDictionary) != nil
{
         print("SUCCESS  ......22....")
        print(json)

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")

                self.Profileddatas.append(MyProfiledData(json:json["myprofile"] as! NSDictionary))
                print("Product Name : ", self.Profileddatas[0].custName)

                self.getvalue ()

         })


}
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution because json["myprofile"] is an optional value and shouldn't be forced into NSDictionary without type-checking.

Comment: @cr0ss in mack code he already mention this  if (json["myprofile"] as? NSDictionary) != nil{  } that his json response have one value that is myprofile so i just give a simple solution to solve his problem and with mine code his problem is solve.

Answer (score 1):

change  `if (json["myprofile"] as? NSDictionary) != nil`
to `if let json = json["myprofile"] as? NSDictionary` because your 'json' in the context of initializing MyProfiledData went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the JSON Data by it's wrong keys in Your MyProfileData Class. You have either pass the ["myprofile"] dict in the init(json) call by

```
if let myProfile = json["myprofile"] as? NSDictionary {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.Profiledatas.append(MyProfileData(json:myProfile))
    })
}
```

or access it by their right Keys:

```
class MyProfiledData {
    var custName : String?
    var custEmail : String?
    var custMobile : String?
    var custAddress : String?
    var custUsername : String?
    var custPassword : String?

    init(json:NSDictionary) {
        self.custName = json["myprofile"]["CustomerName"] as? String
        self.custEmail = json["myprofile"]["CustomerEmail"] as? String
        self.custMobile = json["myprofile"]["CustomerMobile"] as? String
        self.custAddress = json["myprofile"]["CustomerAddress"] as? String
        self.custUsername = json["myprofile"]["CustomerUsername"] as? String
        self.custPassword = json["myprofile"]["CustomerPassword"] as? String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your init function it structure is not ok, it will be work if you send only my profile node of your json

```
 {
    "CustomerName": "ram",
    "CustomerEmail": "ram@gmail.com",
    "CustomerMobile": "",
    "CustomerAddress": "",
    "CustomerUsername": "",
    "CustomerPassword": " "
  }
```

use

```
self.Profileddatas.append(MyProfiledData(json:Json["myprofile"] as NSDictionary))
```